# PHPCR references vs. children

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine-phpcr

I want to migrate my legacy shop system from a relational system to a document based. The reason is obivious: I want to reduce the complexity of relations which describes a shop article, that can have multiple different properties.

So I read the documentation of Doctrine PHPCR and found out, that there are several examples of how to build a model with references, because the main concepts of PHPCR are

- Hierarchy mapping
- References

as described here: [Assocation Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-phpcr-odm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)

But the documentation uses both concepts for the same goal:

**References: Article with author and comments as references**

Example: [Working with Objects](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-phpcr-odm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html)

The article is queried by its ID/path: `/article/hello-world`, the comments and the author are references.

```
/**
 * @ReferenceOne
 */
private $author;

/**
 * @Referrers(referrerDocument="Comment", referencedBy="article")
 */
private $comments;
```

**Hiearchical: Blog user as child document**

Example: [The QueryBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-phpcr-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

It queries the blog user (propably author) by path

```
$qb->from('Blog\User', 'u');

// where name is "daniel"
$qb->where()
  ->eq()->field('u.name')->literal('daniel');
```

Therefore, my main question is, what could be the reason for that, or to be more specific, what are the best practices to build up a model with dynamic properties like a shop article?

```
/article/id:properties[A|B|C]
```

or

```
/article/id/propertyA
/article/id/propertyB
/article/id/propertyC
```

It would be really helpful If someone shares its experience.

Comment: I've realized that Blog\User is no path but a document name, but that doesn't change the essence of the question (imho).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer by myself:

- Use hierarchical references when you want to move documents and rearrange the structure
- Use references to describe/extend the document

For shop articles, its better to use references for properties like name, price, tax ea. and children if you want to have sub articles like bundles.